# Quantum Codes and Plasma Codes for Simulation Applications

Tags: simulation

I am wondering if anyone in here has heard/read is involved in quantum codes applied to simulate plasmas?

I have read that PPNL is working on that but have not actually seen/found any of their papers on the subject.

Thank you!

Comment: IIRC there is work on similar questions by Clader. You may want to look at that and citing works thereof.

Comment: Page 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.2340.pdf is what I was thinking of. Essentially do the same classical algorithms but using HHL when possible.